# Symfony2 embedded forms are nullified despite of cascade_validation being false

Tags: forms, symfony

In a form (ContractType) I need the association to a Customer, which itself has an association to a Company and a BillingAddress. But the data itself of these 3 "nested entities" should not be editable at all in the contract view. That's why the field for the customer ManyToOne-Relation in the contract is hidden.

However for display purposes I need the whole customer-object in the form too (incl. the underlying company and billing address) - but as read-only. This is why I added an additional field **customerFullObject** to the contract form-type - which is not mapped (*mapped => false*). As it is an unmapped field, I set the data via a form event.

Now, when I edit the contract data, the company- and billing-address-data of the customer is nullified.
If I remove/comment the whole **customerFullObject** part, everything is fine.

I don't understand, how/why an unmapped field can change the data of an entity.
How can I prevent Symfony from this? Or is there a better "pattern"/way to achieve what I want? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Below some code snippets from the **model** (removed namespaces for briefness):

#### Contract.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Contract {
    /**
     * @var Customer
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="contracts")
     * @Assert\Type(type="Customer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "customer.notBlank")
     **/
    private $customer;

    // Other fields left out as irrelevant.
}
```

#### Customer.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Customer {
    /**
     * @var Company
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Company")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="company.notBlank")
     **/
    private $company;

    /**
     * @var Address
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="billingAddress.notBlank")
     **/
    private $billingAddress;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Contract", mappedBy="customer", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"all"})
     **/
    private $contracts;

    // Other fields left out as irrelevant.
}
```

#### ContractType.php

```
class ContractType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add(
            'customer',
            'customerHiddenType',
            array(
                'label' => 'contract.customer',
            )
        );

        $builder->add(
            'customerFullObject',
            'customerType',
            array(
                'cascade_validation' => false,
                'mapped' => false
            )
        );

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $editMode = $form->getConfig()->getOption('editMode');
                if (!empty($editMode) && $editMode === RequestAction::CREATE()) {
                    $form->remove('customerFullObject');
                } else {
                    $form->get('customerFullObject')->setData($event->getData()->getCustomer());
                }
            }
        );

        // Other children left out as irrelevant.
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
             array(
                 'data_class' => 'Contract',
                 'cascade_validation' => true
             )
        );
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'contractType';
    }
}
```

#### CustomerType.php

```
class CustomerType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add(
            'company',
            'companyType',
            array(
                'cascade_validation' => false,
                'label' => 'customer.company'
            )
        );

        $builder->add(
            'billingAddress',
            'addressType',
            array(
                'cascade_validation' => false,
                'label' => 'customer.billingAddress'
            )
        );

        // Other children left out as irrelevant.
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
             array(
                 'data_class' => 'Customer',
                 'cascade_validation' => true
             )
        );
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'customerType';
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with embedded forms like this, but have you tried passing a clone customer object here: $form->get('customerFullObject')->setData($event->getData()->getCustomer());

Comment: Rather than an unmapped customer, perhaps map the customer and display as read only.  Or if you don't want to display, the customer could be a hidden field.  Then the controller could set the customer for the contract and all should be persisted nicely.

Comment: @lackovic10 This would work, but the object is quite big and cloning creates a quite big overhead

Comment: @geoB I already have a mapped field for the customer that is hidden to set the relationship between contract and customer. But the hidden field only has information about the Id. However I also need the rest of the information because I want to display some additional information.